# How to check if columnname = 'xyz"' skip adding to xml in the for loop using C# console Application

Tags: c#, xml

I reading the all xml data from db I want skip some columns how to skip some columns while reading in for loop
 Is there any way possible to skip

```
Reading from row node=1 using XMLElement
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
   rowelement.Add(get(col.ColumnName,dr[col.ColumnName].ToString())); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but may be you want something like this

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
  if(!col.ColumnName.ToLower().Equals("xyz"))
   {
     rowelement.Add(get(col.ColumnName,dr[col.ColumnName].ToString())); 
   }
}
```

or may be if you have more columns to skip, then you can take them in List.

```
List<string> columnToSkipped=new List<string>{ "col1", "col2", "col3" };
```

then use your condition like this

```
   if(!columnToSkipped.Contains(col.ColumnName.ToLower()))
   {
      rowelement.Add(get(col.ColumnName,dr[col.ColumnName].ToString())); 
   }
```

Comment: if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dr = dt.Rows[0];
                List<string> columnToSkipped = new List<string> { "p", "k"};

                foreach (DataColumn col in dtAccounts.Columns)
                {
                    if (!columnToSkipped.Contains(col.ColumnName.ToLower()))
                    {
                        rowelement.Add(get(col.ColumnName, dr[col.ColumnName].ToString())); //generating Node for each column
                    }

                }
            }

Comment: so your "p","k" are the column name? or it's data into column. if these are column name then just check why your `if` conditional fails

Answer (score 0):

In C# we have a nice keyword [continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It does precisely what you need. Usage is very simple.

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
   if (someCondition) continue; // this skips the current iteration and proceeds with the loop

   rowelement.Add(get(col.ColumnName,dr[col.ColumnName].ToString())); 
}
```